# "parse error" when I curl to fetch some data and parse it with jq

Tags: curl, jq

```
curl -c - "https://sample.com" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -s | jq .data.name.status
```

how can i fix parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 37, column 3 ?

Comment: The problem is with the data, which you aren't showing us, so this isn't currently answerable. Make sure you're providing a [mre] -- code someone else can run without any changes to see the problem themselves.

Comment: (think about putting `tee somefile.json` into your pipeline between `curl` and `jq`, and looking at line 37 of that file; if it isn't obvious at a glance what's wrong, cut it down to the smallest possible file that causes the same error in the same way _and include it in the question_)

Comment: `-c -` writes the cookies to standard output. This isn't JSON, so `jq` will not accept it.

Answer (score -1):

In problems like this it is important to determine where the error is coming from. Your pipeline is doing two different things: Using `curl` to fetch the data, and then `jq` to parse it. Your first goal is to find out whether it is `curl` or `jq` that is giving you the error.

So, save the results of `curl` to a file:

```
curl -c - "https://sample.com" \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
    -s > data.txt
```

and then if that doesn't give you an error, then you can:

```
jq .data.name.status data.txt
```

This lets you focus on where the problem is.

Comment: See Barmar's comment on the question -- the cause of the error is fairly clear. (And generally, this looks more like an extended comment than an answer as such; it doesn't attempt to answer the question, but rather is providing debugging advice usable to better define where the problem sits)

Comment: Yes, that's right.